# se the value of a property of a object using the value of property of another object

Tags: reactjs

i have to create an array of objects inside the render function.  i need to assign 
a property of an object in array a value inside the render function.

```
    var ref = [{"a":"x","b":"y"];//This is coming through a prop called ref.
    var someArrayOfObject = [{t1:{ref.a}},{t1:{ref.b}}];
```

i am using webpack and babel.  i get an error "Unexpected token".  the error log points to the '.' between ref and the property e.g. ref.a.

i do not receive an error message when i assign {ref.a} to a prop of a component

```
   <SomeComponent someProp={ref.a} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you putting `ref.a` inside `{}`? You were essentially trying to create a object with no key value. Here's the fix:

```
var ref = [{"a":"x","b":"y"];
var someArrayOfObject = [{t1:ref.a},{t1:ref.b}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion here is coming from the JSX syntax for embedding Javascript expressions. When you want use a literal JS expression inside JSX code you need to wrap it in curly parentheses (e.g. `{ref.a}`).

You've tried to use this syntax in your object literal too.

```
[{t1:{ref.a}},{t1:{ref.b}}];
```

We only do this in JSX to show that we're escaping the markup to use a Javascript value. There's no need to do this in normal code. You can safely remove the parens.

```
[{t1:ref.a},{t1:ref.b}];
```

It's also worth mentioning that `ref` is an array not an object, you need to reference the first element inside the array first.

```
var someArrayOfObject = [{t1:ref[0].a},{t1:ref[0].b}];
<SomeComponent someProp={ref[0].a} />
```